# nginx as reverse proxy on front of Apache - protection and security

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, security, reverse-proxy

I'm just concerned whether to install Nginx WS alone or nginx as reverse proxy on front of Apache based on security and protection. If I had to choose nginx as reverse proxy on front of Apache, would the protection and security be applied to both servers? meaning I have to install a security application for each such as mod_security for Apache and mod_security for Nginx, Fail2bn for both servers as well...

can anyone enlighten me here so I can understand how the security should be done??

any comment is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing something like mod_security in only one place - if you're running it on both, configuration and troubleshooting will be a little nightmarish.

So, if you decide to run nginx with mod_security in front of Apache, don't do additional security enforcement in Apache.

Your application needs can dictate whether Apache makes sense, but when possible, keep it simple; if nginx can do all you need, then don't add Apache into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

Such security measures should be applied on front-end server, it is meaningless to repeat same step twice. So in case you use nginx as reverse proxy - then on it.

Using only nginx should be great improvement towards 10k connections per second.

Comment: Thanks. However, what if the connections are over 200K in this case?

Comment: It's not the number what makes difference. They call it C10k [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)